# Iterate through group by result

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have this code which works fine:

```
var groupbyLinq = (from c in lst
                   group c by c.Name into g
                   from d in g
                   select d.Ave).ToList();
```

Now I want the equivalent of the above code in lambda. I tried the below code and it works fine but I'm looking for a way without using the `foreach` loop and unnecessary `List<int>`:

```
var groupbyRcesult = lst.GroupBy(c => c.Name);
List<int> lstAves = new List<int>();
foreach (var item in groupbyRcesult)
{
    lstAves.AddRange(item.Select(student => student.Ave));
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany`:

```
List<int> lstAves = lst
    .GroupBy(c => c.Name)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select(student => student.Ave))
    .ToList();
```

But the query doesn't make sense to me. You're grouping by name and then you are flattening the groups to select the `Ave` property. So you get duplicates again. But it's the method syntax version of your original query. The only thing that is changed from a query `lst.Select(s => s.Ave)` without the `GroupBy+SelectMany` is the order which is somewhat arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks. I know I get duplicates again. I just was curious how can I do that. One more question can I write my original query in a shorter way or it is perfect?

Comment: And can you please explain why should I use `SelectMany` at all?

Comment: @user5032790: because you want to select the `Ave` property from each object in each group. A group can contain multiple(that's why you grouped by the `Name`). If you want to extract all `int` you need to use `SelectMany`. That flattens the groups, similar to your `AddRange(item.Select..)`. `SelectMany` is somewhat the reversal process of `GroupBy`.

Comment: When I use this code lst.GroupBy(c => c.Name).Select(c => c.Select(d => d.Ave)).ToList(); it compiles successfully but it shows me Enumerable as a result. Can you please tell me what is difference between select and SelectMany here?

Comment: @user5032790: it compiles if you don't try to assign the result to a `List<int>` because you get a `List<IEnumerable<int>>`. So the difference is that `Select` returns  `IEnumerable<int>` for each group whereas `SelectMany` returns all ints of all groups.

Answer (score 0):

Using both linq and lambda is the best way.

```
var groupbyLinq = (from c in lst
                   group c by c.Name into g
                   select g).Select(x => new {
                      ave = x.d.Ave
                   }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see your statement converted to a method syntax you can do the 
following, working for any query:

```
var groupbyLinq = (from c in lst.AsQueryable()
                   group c by c.Name into g
                   from d in g
                   select d.Ave);

Console.WriteLine(groupbyLinq.ToString());
```

Comment: I wanted the equivalent of the above code in lambda which is SelectMany.

Comment: Anyway, to be clear, i wanted to say that anything you can do in a method syntax you can also do it using query syntax. So you can do it in a query syntax then convert it to a method syntax using the code i showed above.

Comment: I know that anything I can do in a method syntax I can also do it using query syntax and I have the query syntax myself but I was looking for lambda version of my code that I found I should use SelectMany.